# Send Email to Customer Information on Stripe

Tags: php, html-email, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass the email from Stripe Checkout to the charge.php page that will then send it to the Dashboard so users will get a confirmation email.

Here is my working code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="custom-donation-amount"
     placeholder="50.00" min="0" value="50" step="10.00"/>

          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
          <button id="customButton" class="pay-button">
          <h4 class="donate-text button">Donate by <img src="http://#.com/testing/credit-card.png" ></h4>
          </button>
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_*************',
  image: 'assets/img/#.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
       //this is where I am sending the custom amount, works great. Thought I could do the same with email. 
       $.post( "charge.php", { stripeToken: token.id, amount:$("#custom-donation-amount").val()})
           // log when it works
          .done(function( data ) {
            console.log( "Card charged: " + data );
          });
    }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options
   var amount = $("#custom-donation-amount").val() * 100;
  handler.open({
    name: '*********',
    description: '*********',
    amount: amount
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

**Charge.php**

```
<?php


require_once('init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_***********");


$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$finalamount = $amount * 100; 

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Here's the description", 
  "email" => $email)
);

// Charge the Customer instead of the card
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $finalamount, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later!

// YOUR CODE: When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID!

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount"   => 1500, // $15.00 this time
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customerId
  ));

?>
```

How do I go about grabbing the email address from the Stripe Checkout page? I thought it would work nicely using "stripeEmail" but it turns out that isn't the case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'token' contains the email, replace this:

```
 $.post( "charge.php", { stripeToken: token.id, amount:$("#custom-donation-amount").val()})
```

by this

```
 $.post( "charge.php", { stripeToken: token.id, amount:$("#custom-donation-amount").val(),stripeEmail:token.email})
```

Comment: I'm fairly confident you're a genius.